# Not possible to parse your key passport laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, xampp, laravel-passport, passport-jwt

I have developed API in laravel and then deployed it in the ec2 AWC instance.
I am using xampp. now whenever I want to get a token by sending a request from postman it gives me such sort of error. But it does work when I test in my pc.

```
InvalidArgumentException: It was not possible to parse your key, reason:  in file /opt/lampp/htdocs/AAPi/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/OpenSSL.php on line 90

#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/AAPi/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/OpenSSL.php(47): Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\OpenSSL-&gt;validateKey(Object(OpenSSLAsymmetricKey))
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/AAPi/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/OpenSSL.php(21): Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\OpenSSL-&gt;getPrivateKey('-----BEGIN RSA ...', NULL)
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/AAPi/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/BaseSigner.php(36): Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\OpenSSL-&gt;createHash('eyJ0eXAiOV1Q...', Object(Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key))
```